# add description to image Auk lib

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using Auk lib to present my images in slider and i need to set the description for each image. How i can simply do this? Now I am trying to download the image and then set the description on it:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for picture in LogInViewController.dictionaryForSlider
        {
            //scrollView.auk.show(url: picture.key, accessibilityLabel: picture.value)
            let downloadedPic: UIImage = self.downloadImage(urlStr: picture.key)
            let newPic: UIImage = self.textToImage(drawText: picture.value as NSString, inImage: downloadedPic, atPoint: CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10))

            scrollView.auk.show(image: newPic)
        }

    }


    func textToImage(drawText text: NSString, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
        let textColor = UIColor.white
        let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 12)!

        let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

        let textFontAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: textFont,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: textColor,
            ] as [String : Any]
        image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

        let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)
        text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage!
    }

    func downloadImage(urlStr: String) -> UIImage {
        var img: UIImage? = nil
        var imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(url: imgURL as URL)
        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(
            request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main,
            completionHandler: { response,data,error in
                if error == nil {
                    img = UIImage(data: data!)
                }
        })
        return img!
    }
```

But i got this error:

> 2017-03-25 08:02:04.627615 app1[314:25451] fatal error: unexpectedly
>   found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

on this string:

```
return img!
```

How could I fix it? Or is there any other simple method to set description to image?

Answer (score 0):

I've deal with it without any additional libs/GB of code XD just using UIScrollViewDelegate

```
import UIKit
import Auk

class SliderViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelForInfo: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var navBarTitle: UINavigationItem!

    var lastPoint: CGPoint?
    var listForDescr: [Int : String] = [Int : String]()

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        lastPoint = scrollView.contentOffset
    }
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (lastPoint?.x)! < scrollView.contentOffset.x {
            //print(scrollView.auk.currentPageIndex ?? 0)
            navBarTitle.title = listForDescr[scrollView.auk.currentPageIndex ?? 0]
        }
        else if (lastPoint?.x)! > scrollView.contentOffset.x {
            //print(scrollView.auk.currentPageIndex ?? 0)
            navBarTitle.title = listForDescr[scrollView.auk.currentPageIndex ?? 0]
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scrollView.delegate = self

        labelForInfo.text = ""
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        var count: Int = 0
        for picture in LogInViewController.dictionaryForSlider
        {
            scrollView.auk.show(url: picture.key, accessibilityLabel: picture.value)
            listForDescr.updateValue(picture.value, forKey: count)
            count+=1
        }

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```